# Is it right to customize asp.net identity rather than implementing my own security?

Tags: security, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, simplemembership

I know that its an old thing to do a security for my web application but the new patterns and updates are quickly changed for example for asp.net i don't know how to combine site administration ,membership and role providers, forms authentication ,roles and claims (owin that introduced in katana project )..and if i should implement my own security does it needed to do all stuff on the same pattern as asp.net ?

Comment: Most of the stuff is already done for you if you take default MVC5 project template. Don't implement your own - learn Identity first.

Comment: thanks @trailmax but the confusion is  sometimes about which is the real approach to use that will be suitable to your business requirements and there is one more thing to ask you about ,i can't see if the asp.net identity implements the same  membership and role providers that were used in forms authentication or its completely different mechanism? then the question is more about which one to implement or even implement my own ? thanks

Comment: Identity has it's own RoleManager that is configured through code, not through `web.config`. And please don't implement your own security. Identity framework is very flexible and can do everything (and more) that MembershipProvider used to do.

Comment: thanks very much -@trailmax